# jquery how to set limits for a draggable image

Tags: jquery, html, image, draggable, boundary

i have a draggable image but i cant to set the  boundaries for the image to 1728 by 972.

```
</head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(function() {
    $("#upperMall").draggable();
});

</script>

<body>

<div id="upperMall"><img alt="" height="972" src="images/UpperMall.png" width="1728"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? What do you mean with boundaries for the image?

Comment: @Irvin well if i drag the image to the right or down. it expands the webpage and adds scroll bars. im trying to get it to be draggable within a set space on the webpage.

Comment: The image is bigger than the container div? You want to move the image inside the div?

Comment: @Irvin i think so. so there is a fix "box" that the image is draggable. it just to stop the webpage expanding to the right and own when you drag the image that direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit This in Script

```
$("#upperMall").draggable({ containment: "#container", scroll: false });
```

Add A container Div outside `upperMall` div

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="upperMall">
       .
       .
       .
     </div>

</div>
```

Make the container div bigger than the upperMall div

**CSS**

```
body{overflow-x:hidden}
```

Try This..

Comment: thats stops the image from being draggable

Comment: i know.. i have edited my answer.. u just need to add a div outside upperMall Div.. N make sure the upperMall div is lesser in Dimension Than the Container Div...

Comment: it work to an extent. sorry i wasnt clear. i want it to be bounded by the container div but still able to be drag passed it. so if i drag the image right, it wont expand the webpage but i will be able to drag it all the way right. and if i drag it right the parts that have gone past the boundary are not visible

Comment: u can try to add css and make the body overflow-x:hidden. like this.. body{overflow-x:hidden} it wont let the webpage to expand horizontally